# Did Franco ever refer to his regime as Fascist?

Tags: spain, fascism

Italy certainly started out using the term, which is derived from Senatorial regalia.

Hitler's Germany can also pretty safely be classified as such, that's the regime most people have in mind when referring to Fasciscm.

However, did Franco ever refer to his regime as Fascist, at least during the time when the term had some level of appeal?

I am not looking to equate Franco's regime, as bad as it was, to Hitler's.  Only wondering if he, or his government, **used** the term "Fascism" from Mussolini and Hitler, with whom he had somewhat cordial relations and which started out as equivalently authoritarian/militaristic.

#### Edit re. "most people"

While this is admittedly a sloppy term, there is a strong association in the public mind of Fascism with Hitler's Germany.

Google's ngram are not applicable, but, when searching Google itself, you can see that my claim, while sloppy, has some validity:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119337/discussion-on-question-by-italian-philosophers-4-monica-did-franco-ever-refer-to).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. Franco was a [**Falangist**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falange_Espa%C3%B1ola), and called himself that. *(In real life  more of a military opportunist, who grabbed his chance.)* [Fascists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_Fascism) were the followers of Mussolini. Hitler was a [National-Socialist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazism). Each saw themselves as distinctly different from the other.

Fascist became the generic term for all of them **after** WW2. Mainly because **inter**national socialists were painfully aware how close the words national and international are. Today the term Fascists is essentially meaningless. Just about anybody - regardless of whatever political affiliation - can and has been branded fascist. Even [Trotski](https://buddhistsocialism.weebly.com/leon-trotsky-ndash-the-fascist.html) was called a fascist (by Stalin, I think).

Please follow the link on Trotksi, for a good laugh. I didn't add it because it is a serious article (more the opposite) but to show just about anyone can be called Fascist.

Comment: Yet, Hitler is very much associated with Fascism so would these 3 governments at times have said "we're all the same thing" (before Franco decided to sit out WW2)? I wonder if could edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I don't think Hitler ever referred to himself or NSDAP as fascist in an official speech, even though he did admit being inspired by italian events. These regimes were all called "fascist" by external observers, since the similarities are obvious; but for those political parties it was an image thing - that they emerged from their people, from the *nation*, not just followed Mussolini's example.

Comment: This is incorrect - Franco was not a 'Falangist'. He was not a member of the pre-war Falange, only its 'chief' from 1937 when it was transformed from a fringe group into an instrument of Franco's control. Ideologically Franco was flexible, but on the traditionalist right, favouring the Catholic church, which the 'real' Falange did not.

Comment: "just about anyone can be called Fascist" Pretty much all political labels work this way. Biden gets called leftist and socialist, which is equally laughable.

Comment: @ceejayoz Equally laughable, considering the original meaning of the terms, are "liberal" and "conservative" as used today in describing US politics.

Comment: Just because people misuse a term doesn't make it meaningless. Facism is a well defined ideology in political science. Among other things it is hyper-nationalist, xenophobic, and tends towards authoritarianism.

Comment: "Fascist became the generic term for all of them after WW2." This is patently false. German election poster from 1932 that calls Nazi rule "Fascism": https://www.ebert-gedenkstaette.de/pb/site/Ebert-Gedenkstaette/get/documents_E-171364951/ebert-gedenkstaette.de/Daten/plakatsammlung_pdfs/spd/spd_rtw_juli_1932_2.pdf Russian poster from 1929 that associates the Svastika with fascism: https://www.meisterdrucke.com/kunstdrucke/Deni/777034/Nieder-mit-dem-Faschismus-!,-1929.html

Comment: btw, Franco, did apparently [tangentially refer to his movement as Fascism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definitions_of_fascism#Francisco_Franco) in a 1938 interview.

Comment: @Jan Good finds.

Comment: The English Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definitions_of_fascism has a reference to Bert Brecht's *[Fünf Schwierigkeiten
beim Schreiben der Wahrheit](https://www.gleichsatz.de/b-u-t/spdk/brecht2.html)*, an essay in which his references to Fascism seem to include Germany. He doesn't mention any specific country though -- he saw Fascism in a Marxist-historical perspective as a logical endpoint of Capitalism, not as an issue of specific nations. **The main statement in this answer is wrong.**

Comment: Just because a word is misused doesn't mean it loses its meaning. "Decimate," being an obvious and less controversial example.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I went to the original interview and before those lines quoted in Wikipedia, Franco said "Nuestro Movimiento no corre peligro alguno de sufrir deformaciones extranjeras. Tampoco corre el peligro de "fascistizarse" y aún menos de "marxificarse" -- That is: "Our Movement [the name for falangism] isn't in danger of suffering from foreign deformations. It isn't in danger, either, of turning into "fascism" and even less into "marxism"". So, he clearly said Falangism wasn't fascist.

Comment: (Whether Franco called or considered *himself* Fascist -- the OP's question -- is a separate question which @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica has addressed.)

Comment: @Peter: finding German-language examples for Nazism being described as Fascism is really quite trivial because that equation was so common. That is why I really find this "only after WW2" a bit strange. Another example: https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SPD-Beitragsmarke_Kampf_dem_Faschismus.jpg#mw-jump-to-license

Comment: @Jan: Referring a Communist Party of Germany - SPD: [Sozialdemokratische Partei Deutschlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Democratic_Party_of_Germany) -  propaganda fund raising device alleging the connection is very different from what is being asked - which pertains to *self-identification*.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: Please find the original Spanish for that interview - to protect against translator bias.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens: These comments are concerned with the first sentence of the second paragraph of this answer, which currently reads "Fascist became the generic term for all of them after WW2.". Which is a very surprising statement from a German point of view (as well as for a number of other point of views I think)

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens: btw I think you might also want to read up a bit about the role of the SPD in the Weimar republic.

Comment: I'd challenge OP to find, say, a libertarian that can be in any reasonable sense of the term called "fascist". (No, it doesn't count to just lower your epistemic standards to those followed by pretentious partisans in the dysfunctional democracy that is the US)

Comment: @Jan: well, it did indeed become the generic term for all of them. That doesn't mean you can't call specifically the NSDAP and related entities "Nazi" if you mean them in particular.

Comment: @CarlosMartin [You are correct](http://www.generalisimofranco.com/Discursos/prensa/00028.htm) .  Yes, it is on a site called generalimofranco.com, but if that's the actual he said then that puts the wikipedia quote in a very different light and not a very flattering one.  It's not so much a mistranslation as a deliberate omission of the immediately preceding sentence.  No, not a Franco fan, not in the least, but still.

Comment: @LeifWillerts Your point?  You are the first person to mention "libertarian" here.  This is not a current-politics-in-USA question, it's a question specifically about Franco in the 30s to see if he self-identified Spain as Fascist.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica The Francisco Franco National Foundation, which preserves Franco's documentation, has also the same text for that interview. I also despise Franco, but I'm certain that he said those words and the text has not been changed.

Comment: @NeMo What part of "In real life more of a military opportunist, who grabbed his chance." don't you understand?

Comment: The part where you said something contradictory just before.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I mentioned that as an example of a political faction members of which aren't exactly frequently called "fascist", which I would contend is for a reason: That OPs claim that "just about anyone can be called a fascist" is technically correct (you _can_ call them that, it's not impossible to utter the words), but in fact wrong (you'd often be considered wrong by anyone not extremely prejudiced against whomever you are calling that).

Comment: @LeifWillerts OP here:  you're losing me.  did Franco say "I'm a Fascist and proud of it"?  end of question.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica well, in answering that interesting question, you opted to make a sweeping statement that "just about anyone can be called Fascist", and not in the sense that it's physically possible, but in that the term is diluted to that extent, "essentially meaningless". I objected to that.

Answer (score 11):

The evidence from Franco's own statements strongly suggests that he did not, at least in public. In fact, from 1937, he specifically rejected the term for the Falangists, though he did concede that there were fascists within the movement. He also came close to using the word 'fascist' in a speech in 1938 but deleted it in the final version.

In early 1937 **(my emphasis)**,

> **Franco had declared that it was not a matter of the Falange being a
> “Fascist” movement**: “The Falange has not declared itself fascist; its
> founder [ [José Antonio Primo de Rivera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Antonio_Primo_de_Rivera) ] declared so himself.” Thereafter, the custom within the
> Nationalist zone, especially among the press in the first months, of
> calling the Falangists and some other groups “Fascists” was abandoned.
> All that Franco had been willing to admit before the unification [of the Falangists and the Carlists] was
> that the supposedly non-Fascist character of the Falange “does not
> mean that there are not individual fascists … within it.”

*Source: Stanley G. Payne and Jesús Palacios, '[Franco: A Personal and Political Biography](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/Franco.html?id=rn6aBAAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y)' (2014)*

Nonetheless, Franco's beliefs - and those of the National Movement, as well as its propaganda - were far from being entirely divorced from fascism and, in July 1938, he almost used the word in a speech **(my emphasis)**:

> Franco’s language became somewhat more “Fascist” during 1938 and 1939.
> In the draft of his speech for July 18, 1938, commemorating the second
> anniversary of the National Movement, **he applied the adjective
> “Fascist” to his regime and, more extravagantly, to the Catholic
> monarchs but decided to delete it from the final version.**

*Source: Payne and Palacios*

Note also that Franco was influenced both by the Catholic Church and by monarchists. In fact, even before the end of the civil war, he had spoken of the possibility of eventually restoring the monarchy, and he had strongly opposed the deposing of [Alphonso XIII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfonso_XIII) in 1931.

Answer (score 0):

Franco was for all intents and purposes a fascist.

As Jos pointed out, the official (English) name of his party was ["Falangist"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FET_y_de_las_JONS), which refers to a "phalanx" and indirectly, military rule. But the Wikipedia article points out that Franco took the title "National Chief" which was a "fascist" designation.